# Which Java EE server am I running?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and reading "Learning Continuous Integration with Jenkins." The author writes that "Jenkins can be installed as a service inside the following [Java EE] containers: Apache Geronimo 3.0, GlassFish..." (I think he meant Java EE servers, not containers). To learn the software, I've installed Jenkins in a Docker container using https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/

Given that quote and given that I see the process `java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war`, I suspect that Jenkins is running inside a Java EE server (Java SE can't run a .war can it?), but how do I determine which Java EE server? Is it GlassFish, WebSphere, WildFly, JBoss?

What I've tried so far:

```
jenkins@7154f0e43294:/$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-1~deb9u1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
jenkins@7154f0e43294:/$

jenkins@7154f0e43294:/$ find /opt
/opt
jenkins@7154f0e43294:/$


jenkins@7154f0e43294:/$ find / -iname "*glass*" 2>/dev/null
jenkins@7154f0e43294:/$

jenkins@7154f0e43294:/$ which java
/usr/bin/java
jenkins@7154f0e43294:/$

jenkins@7154f0e43294:/$ ps -auwxf
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
jenkins   1629  0.0  0.0  19964  3656 pts/0    Ss   21:28   0:00 /bin/bash
jenkins   1712  0.0  0.0  38384  3140 pts/0    R+   21:58   0:00  \_ ps -auwxf
jenkins      1  0.0  0.0   1108     4 ?        Ss   19:57   0:00 /bin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
jenkins      7  1.7 10.6 9988328 1741020 ?     Sl   19:57   2:04 java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
jenkins@7154f0e43294:/$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/):

> Jenkins is typically run as a standalone application in its own process with the built-in Java servlet container/application server (Jetty)

Comment: Thank you. That explains this: docker@docker3:~$ docker logs 7154f0e43294 2>&1 | grep jetty | head
`Jan 08, 2018 7:36:21 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet`